# Como fazer uma função para formatar um numero de seguidores?

Tags: php

Como fazer uma função para formatar um numero de seguidores com php?
Tipo no instagram

```
ex: 10000 = 10 k | 1000000 = 1 m
```

Comment: E se for 10200? Ou 1000200? Ou 1200150? Sua pergunta ficou meio rasa.

Comment: Outra coisa importante: você já fez 6 perguntas e não resolveu nenhuma. O que está errado?

Comment: Tem que mostrar que as respostas resolveram seu problema marcando-as como aceitas. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Outra solução caso não queira utilizar `number_format` por que a mesma realiza o arredondamento do valor ao formatá-lo.

```
<?php
function formatarSeguidores($numero, $numeroDivisao)
{
    $numero = $numero / $numeroDivisao;
    $numero = explode('.', $numero);
    $numero[1] = isset($numero[1]) 
        ? substr($numero[1], 0, 1)
        : 0;

    if ($numero[1] == 0)
    {
        return $numero[0];
    }
    return implode(',', $numero);
}

function abreviarSeguidores($numero)
{
    # Se seguidores na casa dos milhões.
    if ($numero >= 1000000)
    {
        return formatarSeguidores($numero, 1000000) . 'm';
    }
    # Se seguidores na casa dos milhares.
    else if ($numero >= 1000)
    {
        return formatarSeguidores($numero, 1000) . 'k';
    }
    return $numero;
}
```

Levando em consideração alguns perfis do Instagram para simular veja o resultado:

```
echo abreviarSeguidores(4468758); #Será impresso: 4,4m
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
echo abreviarSeguidores(323951); #Será impresso: 323,9k
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
echo abreviarSeguidores(20440); #Será impresso: 20,4k
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]